# Other than Bara, what words are used in Genesis for creation?

Tags: genesis, creation

The word "creation" is used 5 times in Genesis 1.  I know that "bara" means to create from nothing.  Is that same word used all 5 times?

Comment: Checking a concordance verifies this as yes. Is there something else that you are looking for?

Comment: בָּרָא _bara_ [Strong 1254](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/1254.htm) occurs, yes, 5 times in Genesis 1. It is used 55 times in the Old Testament (Source : Young's Analytical Concordance). It is usually translated 'create'. In the KJV, (OT) no other words is ever translated 'create', 'created' or 'Creator'.

Comment: Did God "bara" the heavens and the earth, then assemble things after that?

Answer (score 2):

https://biblehub.com/genesis/1-1.htm

Genesis 1:1

> In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.

created
בָּרָ֣א (bā·rā)
Verb - Qal - Perfect - third person masculine singular
Strong's **1254**: To create, to cut down, select, feed

https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H1254&t=KJV&bn=1#lexResults
shows all 5 instances of the word "created" is the Hebrew word H1254.

> I know that "bara" means to create from nothing.

The dictionary meaning does not necessarily mean that. See https://biblehub.com/hebrew/1254.htm

Genesis 1:26a
New International Version

> Then God said, "Let us **make** mankind in our image

“Let Us make
נַֽעֲשֶׂ֥ה (na·‘ă·śeh)
Verb - Qal - Imperfect Cohortative if contextual - first person common plural
Strong's **6213**: To do, make

Answer (score 1):

Bara means " he created". Singular. This matches what Jesus said in Mark 13:19, Matthew 19:4 and Mark 10 :6. Jesus ascribed creation to God, not himself.

Mark 13:19 ASV For those days shall be tribulation, such as there hath not been the like from the beginning of the creation which God created until now, and never shall be

Mark 10:6 ASV But from the beginning of the creation, Male and female made he them.

Matthew 19:4 ASV And he answered and said, Have ye not read, that he who made them from the beginning made them male and female

Jesus himself was created. John 3:16 and Revelation 3:14.

Comment: This is getting away from the "Bara" question but I'm getting red flags .  John 1:1-3 tells us Jesus was God and that he made everything that was made.   Though Jesus attributed creation to God, He was attributing it to Himself.  John 3:16 only directs us to the trinity.   Revelation 3:14 only tells us that God created.  To conclude that Jesus was created doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of words words used for "creating" in Gen 1.  Here is a sample:

1. **בָּרָא (bara)** = "created", Gen 1:1, 21, 27, 2:3, etc.
2. **הָיָה (hayah**) = "come to pass", Gen 1:2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 19, 23, 24, 29, 30, etc.
3. **בָּדל (badal)** = "divided", Gen 1:4, 6, 7, 14, 18 [This verb only occurs in the first three days' activities]
4. **עָשָׂה (asah)** = "make", Gen 1:7, 11, 12, 16, 25, 31, 2:2, 3, etc.
5. **קָוָה (qavah)** = "collect", Gen 1:9 [only once in the creation account and only on day #3]
6. **רָאָה (ra'ah)** = "see" or "appear", Gen 1:4, 9, 10, 12, 18, 21, 25, 31, etc.
7. **דָּשָׁא (dasha)** = "sprout", Gen 1:11
8. **נָתַן (nathan)** = "put" or "set", Gen 1:17, 29 [This only occurs in the second three days of creation]
9. **שָׁרַץ (sharats)** = "swarm" or "team", Gen 1:20, 21 [Only occurs in the second three days]
10. **יָצָא (yatsa)** = "go/come out", Gen 1:12, 24

These verbs describing God's activity should be seen in the context of the initial description of the earth (V2) as: **תֹּהוּ (tohu)** = formless, and, **בֹּהוּ (bohu)** = empty.  Then

- in the **first three days** God separates and shapes/forms the earth; #1 - light separated from darkness; #2 - waters above separated from waters below; #3 - dry land separated from seas
- in the **second three days** God fills the three environments he had created: #4 - lights in the heavens; #5 - creatures in sea and birds in the air; #6 - land creatures and mankind.

**APPENDIX - Hebrew בָּרָא (bara)** from BDB lexicon

> I. בָּרָא53 verb shape, create (compare Arabic  probably loan-word,
> form, fashion by cutting, shape out, pare a reed for writing, a stick
> for an arrow, but also , create; Phoenician הברא CISi. 347 incisor, a
> trade involving cutting; Assyrian barû, make, create, COTGloss & Hpt
> KAT2Gloss 1 but dubious; Sabean ברא found, build, DHMZMG 1883, 413,
> synonym בנה; BaZA. 1888, 58, compare Assyrian banû, create, beget,
> with change of liquid; Aramaic בְּרָא, , create) — Qal Perfect Genesis
> 1:1 19t.; Imperfect יִבְרָא Genesis 1:21,27; Numbers 16:30; Infinitive
> בְּראֹ Genesis 5:1; Imperative בְּרָא Psalm 51:12; Participle בּוֺרֵא
> Isaiah 42:5 10t.; suffix בֹּרַאֲךָ Isaiah 43:1; בּוֺרְאֶיךָ
> Ecclesiastes 12:1; — shape, fashion, create, always of divine
> activity, with accusative of thing, seldom except in P and Isa2.
>
> 1 object heaven and earth Genesis 1:1; Genesis 2:3 (P) Isaiah 45:18
> (twice in verse); mankind Genesis 1:27 (3 t. in verse); Genesis
> 5:1,2(P) Genesis 6:7 (J) Deuteronomy 4:32; Psalm 89:48; Isaiah 45:12;
> the host of heaven Isaiah 40:26; heavens Isaiah 42:5; ends of the
> earth Isaiah 40:28; north and south Psalm 89:13; wind Amos 4:13; the
> תנינים Genesis 1:21 (P).
>
> 2 the individual man Malachi 2:10 ("" father) Ecclesiastes 12:1; the
> smith and the waster Isaiah 54:16 (twice in verse); Israel as a nation
> Isaiah 43:15; Jacob Isaiah 43:1; the seed of Israel Isaiah 43:7.
>
> 3 new conditions and circumstances: righteousness and salvation Isaiah
> 45:8; darkness and evil Isaiah 45:7; fruit of the lips Isaiah 57:19; a
> new thing חֲדָשָׁה (a woman encompassing a man) Jeremiah 31:22;
> בְּרִיאָה (swallowing up the Korahites) Numbers 16:30 (J); cloud and
> flame over Zion Isaiah 4:5.
>
> 4 of transformations: a clean heart Psalm 51:12 ("" חִדֵּשׁ); new
> heaven and earth Isaiah 65:17 (in place of old); transformation of
> nature Isaiah 41:20; with double accusative בורא ירושׁלם גילה
> transform Jerusalem into rejoicing Isaiah 65:18.
>
> Niph`al Perfect2feminine singular נִבְרֵאתְ Ezekiel 21:35; 3plural
> נִבְרְאוּ Exodus 34:10 2t.; Imperfect יִבָּרֵא֑וּן Psalm 104:30;
> Infinitive suffix הִבָּרַאֲךָ Ezekiel 28:13; הִבָּֽרְאָךְ Ezekiel
> 28:15; הִבָּֽרְאָם Genesis 2:4; Genesis 5:2; Participle נִבְרָא Psalm
> 102:19; — Pass.
>
> 1 be created: heaven and earth Genesis 2:4 (P); creatures Psalm
> 104:30; mankind Genesis 5:2 (P); heavens Psalm 148:5.
>
> 2 with reference to birth: במקום אשׁר נבראת in the place where thou
> wast created (i.e. native land) Ezekiel 21:35; יום הבראך day when thou
> wast created (king of Tyre) Ezekiel 28:13,15 (compare היום ילדתיך
> Psalm 2:7); עַם נִבְרָא Psalm 102:19 ("" עַם נוֺלָד Psalm 22:32).
>
> 3 of something new, astonishing: miracles Exodus 34:10 (J); new
> things, חדשׁות Isaiah 48:6.
>
> Pi`el Perfect בֵּרֵאתָ Joshua 17:15; בֵּרֵאתוֺ Joshua 17:18;
> Infinitive absolute בָּרֵא Ezekiel 21:24 (twice in verse); Ezekiel
> 23:47; —
>
> 1 cut down: a forest Joshua 17:15,18 (J); וּבָרֵא אוֺתְהֶן
> בְּחַרְבוֺתָם Ezekiel 23:47.
>
> 2 cut out: יָד hand, as an index Ezekiel 21:24 (twice in verse).
>
> II. [בָּרָא] verb be fat (Arabic  be free of a thing, sound, healthy;
> see מרא) —
>
> Hiph`il Infinitive לְהַבְרִיאֲכֶם 1 Samuel 2:29 to make yourselves
> fat.

Comment: If 1:27 is Bara it conflicts with 2:7 that says He formed man from the dust of the ground.  Your thoughts?

Comment: @Randy the verb "bara" appears in Gen 1:27 three times.  In Gen 2:7 it is יָצַר yatsar.  Their meanings overlap as both can mean "formed".  But the process is not the primary meaning - it is the creation of life that is important